# TypeError: errorResponse.json is not a function - Tried to remove holding response as Json but still facing issue

Tags: json, angular, service, httpclient, typeerror

Angular 8:

I am facing "TypeError: errorResponse.json is not a function" error.
I am trying to read data from json file, but while fetching the response in service is throwing error.
JSON file format is correct, I feel there is some error while holding the json response.

Please help me with fixing this error.

Her is my code in Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d2ada1?file=src/app/article.service.ts

Comment: The url to which you are requesting the json from does not return a json:

Comment: See in network console, if the request is returning json response.

Comment: I inspected and found that request is going to `https://angular-j791rz.stackblitz.io/assets/data/newarticle.json` but response is not json.

Comment: Hi thank you for taking a look. I removed holding the response as json but still i am facing the same issue.

Comment: Please let me know how to hold the json response in this case. I have updated code in stackbliz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d2ada1?file=src/app/article.service.ts

Comment: Solved. Tried replacing local file with file from a fake json server. https://my-json-server.typicode.com/